# Django - ModelForm is saving even though data is invalid

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

Sort of.

I have a modelform defined like so:

```
class EditUserForm(UserForm):
    def __init__(self,data=None,instance=None):
        UserForm.__init__(self,data=data,instance=instance)
        del self.fields['username']
```

I did this because I wanted to exclude the username field from displaying on my EditUserForm but because I overwrote the username field in UserForm, a bug in django prevents this from working so I wrote the form in this way.

My view code looks like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = EditUserForm(request.POST,instance=user)
        upf = StudentProfileForm(request.POST,instance=profile)
        if uf.is_valid() and upf.is_valid(): 
            print 'VALID'
            uf.save()
            upf.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated your profile.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/student/editprofile')
        else:
            print 'INVALID'
```

To test it, I tried changing the firstname and making the passwords not match and when I submitted I noticed that INVALID was printed (the passwords validation error correctly appeared) BUT on the top of the page where I have "Welcome (the users first name) (the users last name)" I noticed that the first name had changed.  When I go to a different page, it goes back to the correct value.  How do I make this not happen?

This is my html code:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Welcome, <a href = "/{{user.get_profile.getType}}/profile">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</a> | 
    <a href = "/auth/logout">Logout</a>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

My guess as to what's happening is, when I post the data, it puts user.first_name in the context overwriting the actual's user.first_name.  But it's not valid because the data isn't saved yet...

**So**, how can I have user.first_name in a template that's being posted to without changing it's value until it's actually valid??

Comment: Please show the rest of the code of that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is right. Upon validation, the `ModelForm` updates the given instance (`user`) with the given `data`, leaving it in an invalid state.

You could:

- try to create a copy of `user`,
- reload the `user` from database,
- or store `user.first_name` in a temporary variable and set it back upon validation failure

Edit: note that although the ModelForm modifies the instance, it doesn't save it.

Comment: I think what I may do is create a "display_name" field in my UserProfile and use that to display the users name in the template.  On the UserProfile save, I'll set display_name = user.first_name+user.last_name